# how to Print ten dates, each two a week apart, starting from today, in the form YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, python-datetime

How to print ten dates, each two a week apart, starting from today, in the form YYYY-MM-DD

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today()

print(now.year)
print(now.month)
print(now.day)
print(now.date())

myDate = now.date()

for i in range(14, 140, 14):
   print(myDate)
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop

Comment: used it , but not sure how to increment the dates, if i inc the date how the month will be incremented and the year as well?

Comment: thanks @bradbury9 the follwing code worked.
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.today()

print(now.year)
print(now.month)
print(now.day)

myDate = now.date()

for i in range(1, 140, 14):
    print(myDate)
    myDate = myDate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

dates = []

now = datetime.datetime.today()


for i in range(1, 15):
     day = now.day + i

     date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-' + str(day))

     dates.append(date)

     print(date)
```

Here is your output:

```
2018-04-17
2018-04-18
2018-04-19
2018-04-20
2018-04-21
2018-04-22
2018-04-23
2018-04-24
2018-04-25
2018-04-26
2018-04-27
2018-04-28
2018-04-29
2018-04-30
```

I wasn't sure if you would want to store the dates for some reason, so I also appended them to an empty list if you want to work with the dates later or store them for some reason.

Comment: this just inc the date by 1 day, i want the day to inc by 14 days and logically inc the month and year

Comment: Okay, I’ll edit this.